# Почему Android Studio ловит breakpoint на var внутри if?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Почему breakpoint работает во втором if а в первом нет?

```
val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = bluetoothManager.adapter
if(bluetoothAdapter == null) { 
  Log.e("error", "device doesn't support Bluetooth");
}
if(bluetoothAdapter == null) {
  var a = 5
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно при компиляции оптимизируется код

Comment: @ArtyMorris я тоже думал но не срабатывал скорее бы

Comment: Компилятор возможно его игнорирует, повтор

Comment: Переменная не используется нигде и поэтому выбрасывается. Нужно добавить ниже использование этой `a`

Comment: Закопипастил, проверил у себя - все брекпоинты срабатывают